how to add a different label or different value to plot title, per facet
I need to add an R-squared value to each facet of the facet grid or facet wrap of Python's letsplot plotting library.
So far I can't figure a way to do it, nor does it seems that there is a way to itterate on the plot obect, g, in this case, in order to add labels or alter titles, per facet, or perhaps I am missing something?
In this example, how do I add different labels or/and different values to titles>
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from lets_plot import *
LetsPlot.setup_html()
import seaborn as sns

pengu = sns.load_dataset('penguins').dropna()
g = (
    ggplot(pengu, aes(x = 'body_mass_g', y = 'bill_length_mm',))
    + geom_point(aes(color = 'species'))
    
    # + geom_smooth(aes(color='species'))
    + geom_smooth(aes())
    

    + ggmarginal('tr',layer=geom_density())
    + ggmarginal('tr',layer=geom_histogram( aes(fill='species'),alpha = 0.25, size = 0.25))
    + ggmarginal('bl', size = 0.05, layer=geom_boxplot(aes(color = 'species'),size = 0.4,))
    
    + facet_wrap(facets=['sex','island',], format = '{d} \nhow to add different text per plot?\nI need an R^2 value here')
    + labs(title='A facet grid of penguins', subtitle='colorful penguins', caption='caption' )

    + geom_label(x=4500, y=58, label='How to put different label \nper facet?', size=10)
    + xlab('body_mass_g') + ylab('bill_length_mm')
    + ggsize(1500,1000)
    + theme_bw()
    )
g

This is the plot I am talking about:

I've tried looking at the methods of the plot object, g, but I couldn't find a way to alter it so the values would change, but I am by far no expert on those matters and I would appreciate some help.
